# Is there a way to know if permissions were removed on the Facebook website

Tags: android, facebook

My workflow is as follows: when opening an existing Session (I don't use the default LoginButton), I only ask for read permissions. Once granted, I ask for publish_actions.
If the user does not want to grant publish_actions, I set a flag and never ask for it again (SharedPreferences).

However, all permissions can be removed on Facebook and in this case I'd like to do a clean reset and ask for all permissions again.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I do know that the Session object contains a list of all permissions once opened, but I cannot know whether they were recreated after deletion.